# What is a jig?

Tags: tools

What is the process called, when you create a shape of wood which will only be used during making the end product. Say if you want to glue 2 panels of wood together (butt them together) at a certain angle, say 67 degrees. You could get 2 blocks of wood, and on one cut an inset out, with sides 67 degrees apart, and then on the other create an outset which is 67 degrees, so that both pieces fit together.

You can then sandwich the panels of wood between these two specifically created blocks and clamp it tight, so you will be certain they will glued at 67 degrees.

The created blocks can then be reused for all other panels you want to glue to each other at 67 degrees.

I know there could be a better way of glueing 2 panels, but I need to know what this process is called? Or/and what the blocks that are only used during building are called?

EDIT: after looking a bit more (typical, finding the answer after asking here) it seems this is called a jig? Is this right?

(double question marks in title to make 15 characters)

Comment: Jig, form - yep!

Comment: I've upvoted Scott Saunders' answer. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Officially that's a "fixture". A fixture is like a jig except that (officially) a jig guides a tool, while a [fixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixture_%28tool%29) does not.

In the real world (unofficially) if you call that a jig, everyone will know what you're talking about.